# local.settings.json ignored for Java Azure Functions

Tags: java, intellij-idea, azure-functions, maven-3, appsettings

I have followed doc guidance on how to setup java azure functions project with InteliJ: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-maven-intellij

Nevertheless when trying to use local.settings.json file to inject application settings when running Functions locally, values are not injected and the file is ignored by the runtime.
Is there a way how to make use of local.settings.json as with C# functions? For time being I used workaround of adding values into run configuration.

I am using Java 8, Azure Functions Core tools 4.x

Answer (score 1):

if you created the skeleton using microsoft help:

`mvn archetype:generate "-DarchetypeGroupId=com.microsoft.azure" "-DarchetypeArtifactId=azure-functions-archetype" "-DjavaVersion=8"`

in your pom.xml you should find a section that does copy the local setting into the target folder

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-resources</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                <outputDirectory>${stagingDirectory}</outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${project.basedir}</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>host.json</include>
                            <include>local.settings.json</include>
                        </includes>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-extensions-lib</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                <outputDirectory>${stagingDirectory}/.azurefunctions</outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/.azurefunctions</directory>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Install the azure function core tools:

```
brew tap azure/functions
brew install azure-functions-core-tools@4
# if upgrading on a machine that has 2.x installed
brew link --overwrite azure-functions-core-tools@4

#Install extensions
func extensions install
```

Then you can either run with:

`mvn clean package azure-functions:run -DenableDebug -Dverbose=true`

and attach your intellij debugger `Run->Debug->attach to process` or attach to `localhost:5005`

this will honour the `local.settings.json` and let you debugging

As far as i know the Azure Function run from intellij needs the parameters specified in the app settings.

Comment: thank you for answer @Paizo, I have create project directly thru inteliJ function extension, but it did not added lines you stated. When I compared to vs code created project, those lines are neither present, but I suppose VS Code Functions extensions takes care of local settings file being used. Ultimately I decided to change to VS Code as the dev experience for Azure Functions seems to be better than for InteliJ.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `local.settings.json` from `.gitignore` file and publish/deploy the function.

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: this is not actually my problem, I want to run the function locally and have the values stated in local.settings.json file injected into run environment

Comment: Could you please provide the code how you are injecting the local.settings.json in your run environment or can you confirm that you want to use local.settings.json configuration values in the Function code?

Comment: Hey @Pravallika, thank you for comment. I have create project directly thru inteliJ function extension, but it did not added lines you stated. As sated for response below when I compared InteliJ created project to vs code one, those lines are neither present, but I suppose VS Code Functions extensions takes care of local settings file being used. Ultimately I decided to change to VS Code as the dev experience for Azure Functions seems to be better than for InteliJ.

Comment: @marek_lani, For Azure Functions .NET Stack - VS IDE is best suitable. For Azure Functions (Python, JS, Java, etc.,) Stacks - VS Code is best I believe as per my experience.